# Open fragment in Tab

Tags: android

I have an activity that is composed of a TabLayout and a ViewPager. The TabLayout is divided into two tabs. The layout of this activity is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="One"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Two"/>    

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</FrameLayout>
```

On the other hand I have two activities. In one, some data is retrieved to be displayed in a ListView, and this screen is displayed in the first tab of the TabLayout. The layout of this window, TAB_A, is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbtnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:elevation="1dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lstComunicaciones" />

</FrameLayout>
```

How do you see, I have a floating button. Well, I want that when pressing on that button, in the same first tab, a second window opens occupying the space where TAB_A used to be. It is TAB_B, and its code is this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried FragmentTransaction:

```
fbtnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            TabB newFragment = new TabB();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment, "NewFragment");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

But this does not work. When you click on the button the activity TAB_A disappears, but the activity TAB_B does not appear. Instead, everything goes blank, but nothing is shown.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!